# C# Temporarily unassign event handler for serialisation?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I have an object graph which contains one object which fires events.

I want to serialise this graph, however I occasionally plug handlers into the event which belong to non-serialisable classes, nor do I want those non-serialisable objects to be serialised in the first place.

Basically, non-serialisable things like calendars, reports, graphs, etc. plug into the data graph and the events are for things like updates, etc. I want to serialise my data graph, but not my reports, calendars, etc.

When I try to serialise my data graph, I get an exception if the event delegate is not null, as the handling classes are non-serialisable. I have code in those Forms such that when I close them, the handlers disconnect, so I can save my data graph as long as I've closed all calendars, reports, etc.

The logical solution would seem to be:

1. Set a temporary variable equal to the current state of the event handlers, be it null or otherwise.
2. Set the event handlers to null.
3. Serialise my data graph.
4. Set the event handlers back to what they were before.

However this doesn't work because I'm getting a compile-time error telling my my event can only exist on the left side of += or -=

How can I remove all handlers temporarily while I serialise, and then set them back afterwards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try applying `[field:NonSerialized]` to your event?

Comment: You were faster. I can just add link to an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182349%28v=vs.80%29.aspx :)